# MVC ViewData not rendering in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my post action method for Edit.

```
            JobCardService.Update(viewData.JobCard);
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ViewData["Notifications"] = js.Serialize(new {NoteificationType = "Success", Message = "The installtion was successfully updated"});
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

However, on the client, ViewData is null/empty, i.e. this client code

```
var notifications = eval("<%= ViewData["Notifications"]%>");
```

renders as

```
var notifications = eval("");
```

I'm sure I'm doing something small wrong.

Comment: I'm confused, why do you have a redirectToAction in an Ajax call?

Comment: It's not an ajax call.  I'm not using JSON for the whole response, I just want to add it to the response.

Comment: eval needs 'padding' in order to work. try this instead: eval("(" + "<%= ViewData['Notifications']%>" + ")");

Comment: note as well that you're not escaping your string correctly, you should have single quotes around anything contained in your double quotes.

Comment: No joy @jim, the js code is being rendered as:
eval('');
It doesn't even get as far as a broken eval.  There just isn't anything for it to even try eval'ing.

Comment: It certainly is jim, but I have no idea what you mean by putting a model on the index view?  I know I can set viewdata in the get action for the index, but how do I pass the notifications to it?

Comment: one last throw - couldn't you put a model on the index view (if not already there) which had those attributes?? i know it doesn't address the issue directly but often pragmatism is key.. also, you could try using TempData instead of ViewData as the ViewData is linked to the edit controller and NOT the index one

Comment: ProfK - i was meaning a strongly typed model i.e. along these lines: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Shareholder.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SubSonic.Web.Models.Fund>" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProfK - I think (as you'll no doubt be aware) you'll have to parse that json result in javascript once you get into your index view via the redirect. the jquery .getJson() method would seem most appropriate: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Also, as you're doing a RedirectToAction, then the context of the ViewData will be lost. In that case, you want to use TempData as a drop in replacement. Below is an example of what you could try:

jim

**[edit]** - not sure if this would work:

```
// in the controller
TempData["Notifications"] = js.Serialize(...);

// in the index view
function getMyJsondata() {
    var json = $.getJson('<%=ViewContext.TempData["Notifications"] %>');
}
```

or as per your amendment to the question, try this:

```
// alternative in index view
eval("(" + "<%= TempData['Notifications']%>" + ")");
```

give it a go...

adendum:
to quote from a previous SO question on Tempdata vs ViewData: [What is TempData collection used for in asp.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313572/what-is-tempdata-collection-used-for-in-asp-net-mvc)

> TempData is used to share data between
>   controller actions. If your controller
>   does a RedirectToAction and the target
>   action needs data (perhaps a
>   particular model instance) to act
>   upon, you can store this data in
>   TempData. Using TempData is similar to
>   storing it in the session, but only
>   for one round-trip. You use TempData
>   when you need to pass data to another
>   controller action rather than a view
>   for rendering.

Comment: Thanks @jim, but my problem is now that that ViewData is simply not appearing on the client.

Comment: ProfK - try using TempData (in the same way), rather than ViewData. TempData is session based, whereas ViewData is linked to that controller action (i.e. the Edit action)

Comment: Thanks, but TempData gave me the same issue.  I have made master page typed for BaseViewData and moved my notifications collection to that class.  I'll recheck TempData later, but for now things are wworking.