# Difference between TempData and ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference Between ViewData and TempData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata)

What is major difference between TempData and ViewData?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already answered at: [Difference Between ViewData and TempData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata)

HTH