# Passing useful message from a controller to another redirected controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I want to make a RedirectToAction after the user clicks a button. Before I redirect, I store the information into a variable. At the end, after I have  redirected to action, I want to show some useful information. I tried this:

```
ViewBag.message = "User with ID = " + id + " was changed status to verified.";
```

But the data will be flushed after redirection. 
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `TempData`.

```
TempData["message"] = "User with ID = " + id + " was changed status to verified.";
```

It is stored in session but after you access it, it will be removed.

Here are some useful links

[Passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Difference Between ViewData and TempData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Comment: Thx, dude =D finally found my solution ^^ i'm new to MVC and finally get it.

Comment: one more noob question to ask, may i know why i try to check if this method verify(int id) with if(id != null) else, the code cannot reach else when i type abc.com/verify/ but return me exception The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id', may i know usually how to check what is there value pass in to the method ? Thx

Comment: @Spencer its not clear what you are asking. but its pointless to check whether an `int` variable is `null`.

Comment: anyway, Thx =D i try to find other approach >.< i mean let say, i got a method called verify, when people visit abc.com/verify/, it will got error, if people visit abc.com/verify/123, it will be fine and execute the function...i want to handle the error by displaying a message, in the way of check if(id != null) else, it return me this message "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'"