# Hold a data object temporarily

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `object` that i want to store for a moment. The object is in a controller for now, the controller will generate a view. A `AJAX` request is made from the view to next controller. For that moment i need the object previously stored. Previously, i used `session` and it worked well. But not sure it is the right thing to do. Is `session` the answer for this or is there anything else?

**P.S.** I need to access the data multiple time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing useful message from one controller to redirected controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978253/passing-useful-message-from-one-controller-to-redirected-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your object to cache.

Add:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("MyData", myObject, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(6),
                        System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
```

Retrive object:

```
var my object = HttpContext.Current.Cache["MyData"] as MyType
```