# asp.net mvc keep object alive, information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
       // some lines of code . bla bla bla
       TempData["loginModel"] = loginModel;
       return RedirectToAction("index", "premium");
     }
     ...
}
```

and this controller here

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var loginModel = TempData["loginModel"] as LoginModel;
   ...
}
```

now, when the page loads, everything seems to work fine. but when i refresh, everything messes up, it says that the loginModel is like null. the question is, how can i like keep track of the current login users. i have forms authentication enabled. tnx

error is as below

---

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 22: 
Line 23:             var loginModel = TempData["loginModel"] as LoginModel;
Line 24:             string username = loginModel.username;
Line 25:             string password = loginModel.password;
Line 26:             premiumModel.username = username;
```

Comment: also, when we refresh the page, it doesnt go to [HTTPPOST] since its not a post type. it goes to ordinary controller, how can the ordinary controller know its the same visitor, and know the username and password. it has cookie enabled. any ideas?

Comment: by the way, TempData stores their values until next access, so you can use value only one time, this is about why it names like that =)

Comment: @Alexander any idea how to use controller.user property ? tnx

Comment: just use `this.User` somewhere in action of your controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Confusion**

> but when i refresh, everything messes up, it says that the loginModel
>   is like null

**Answer**

This is due to the fact that you have read the `TempData` key and Once it is read, data will be lost for that particular key.

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"] //Once read, data will be lost
```

---

**Question**

> how can i like keep track of the current login users

**Answer**

So to persist the data even after the data is read you can Alive it like below

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"];
TempData.Keep();                 //Data will not be lost for all Keys
TempData.Keep("keyName");        //Data will not be lost for this Key
```

`TempData` works in new Tabs/Windows also, like `Session` variable does.

You could use `Session` Variable also, Only major problem is that `Session` Variable are very heavy comparing with `TempData`. Finally you are able to keep the data across Controllers/Area also.

Hope this post will help you alot.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to store the user's identity (username) once the user is authenticated - password is not needed. As such ASP.NET authentication already supports storing user's identity in the authentication cookie and you don't have to re-invent the wheel. You can get the identity using [Controller.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx) property.

EDIT: I am assuming that you have set up your application correctly for Forms Authentication. Regardless, here are few how-to/tutorial links that start you on it:

1. http://www.apexa.net/Blog/web_design_Blog_20100319.aspx
2. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs
3. Explain solution so that you don't have to apply Authorize attribute on every action - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Comment: tnx, cant find a way how to use Controller.User property. any ideas>?

Comment: `Controller.User` isn't a static property --- you need an instance of a `Controller` class. Your controller inherits the `Controller` class, so when you are in your controller action methods like your `Index()` action, `this.User` gives you the user object.

Comment: @nekno, cant create an object because controller class is abstract or interface bro. try it if u want. any ideaS? tnx

Comment: @user963499, as nekno pointed out, simply use `this.User` inside your controller code

Comment: @user963499 - From within one of your action methods, like the two `Index` actions you posted, you would use `this.User`. If you want to get a reference to the user in your view, you can use the `Context.User` property, i.e., `@Context.User.Identity.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

`TempData` does only live for one request. Therefore it's empty when you make the second request. If you'd want to do it like this you should use `Session` instead or you can have a look at [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx).

You should also consider VinayC advice and not store any password information in any state, especially not in clear text format.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a new MVC 3 project in Visual Studio via File > New. It will set up forms authentication for you, so you can see the best practices for the login and registration pages, signing the user in/out with the session cookie, and displaying user info like username.

Comment: controller is static class, how can i access controller.user  cant acces it. tnx

Comment: No, `Controller` is NOT a static class. Your controller, i.e. your `AccountController`, or `LoginController`, or whatever controller class you're in where you posted your code for the `Index` actions --- **that** is a controller class. Inside that code, you can use `this.User` if you have properly set up your controller to inherit from the `Controller` class, i.e., `public class AccountController : Controller`. I don't even know how your code would work as an MVC controller if it didn't properly inherit from `Controller`.