# Dropdown list with Razor instead of <select> with HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a select list like that one

```
  <select id="select-product">
            <option>Select a Product</option>
  </select>
```

I fill in this list using Ajax at runtime, now I want to convert it to a razor view and I will include the data in Viewbag before redirecting to the page.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

> I will include the data in Viewbag before redirecting to the page.

A common (and good) method is to use `@Html.DropDownList()` or `@Html.DropDownListFor<>()` in your view. However, you should prefer strongly-typed models over less-structured data in the `ViewBag`.

See also:

- [How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)
- [When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in Mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046637/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('/Home/GetProducts/' + $(this).val(), function (response) {
        var products = $.evalJSON(response);
        var ddlSelectedProduct = $("#SelectedProduct");

        // clear all previous options 
        $("#SelectedProduct > option").remove();

        // populate the products 
        for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            ddlSelectedProduct.append($("<option />").val(products[i].Value).text(products[i].Text));
        }
    });
});
```

Or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedProductId, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Products as SelectList, "Value", "Text"),
    "-- Select Product--"
)
```