# Passing Data Between Pages - Session Vs. Saving in DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-variables

The idea has always been to use session as little as possible, for extensive use of it will slow down the page. Nowadays, computer has significant amount of memories, so using session should not be as much of an issue as it used to be in the earlier years. 
Some folks have made a security argument as to why session should not be used.  In my opinion, you have to worry about security issue no matter what option has been chosen.

I've also been advised to use query string to append the end of the URL in order to pass data between pages. In some cases, I am passing string of data that is quite long, and they all visible in the URL.

My solution was to create an object with all possible data that I may need to share between pages and create a session wrapper for that object. It works fine, but I am still not sure if that is the best way of doing it.

I've gotten so many answers and have seen it done so many ways thAt I don't know any more.

What is the best way of going about passing data between pages?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to pass between pages? Any sample or idea of what really you want to pass? May be we can come up with a better solution than these two..

Comment: `TempData' is the good option. You can keep the `TempData` as per your conditions. `TempData.Keep()` to persist all `Keys` and `TempData.Keys["SpecificKey"]` to keep particular key. **[Check this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199709/2015869)**. Even you don's need `Query Strings`. This purpose will be resolved by `TempData`. It works like `Sessions`. Keeps the data across `Tabs/Windows`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mainly passing Student Information between pages. The user may pull record for one student. In some cases, the students can have a large amount of data associated with his/her record. Someone in Financial Aid may want to view that records, and they may decide to go over to the insurance page, where they would also want to see some of the information from the financial aid page. 
In addition, if the student meet certain criteria, the health department may decide to pull that student medical record for whatever reason. If the student has an outbreak in school, they have to update several pages. In some of the pages, the information is exactly the same, so it would not make sense for them to type it over when I can import it from the previous page. Although this information has been saved in the database, I am trying to save an additional trip to the DB by keeping it in the session.