# How to read child page viewbag variable in parent master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have stumbled upon this situation where I set a viewbag variable inside a MVC controller, but can't read it inside the master page, the viewbag variable shows always null in the masterpage.

I suspect that this is because the masterpage is being rendered before the page controller call, but still I need to somehow communicate backwards.

Comment: You may need **[Tempdata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199709/2015869)**.

Comment: Reason to not use `ViewBag` is that when you reach layout page that time it is redirected from my view request that means second request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 100% agree with @Chase Florell but to answer you question directly, I believe you can just use ViewContext.Viewbag

Comment: It turns out that I was setting the Viewbag.x variable inside an IF statement that does never hit. Moving the Viewbag.x = true outside of the IF solved the issue. There is no need to use ViewContext, because Viewbag.x is enough.

Comment: In partial views, I believe you have to use Controller.ViewContext.ViewBag("MyBag")

Answer (score 0):

Without further info into your business logic, I could be way off base here... but... It seems that setting any ViewBag data in the View is an [Anti-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

By the time the View is getting rendered as it's part of the Life Cycle of a page, your `ViewModel` should have everything it needs, and the View and Masterpage should just consume the data, not generate it.

I'm also a FIRM believer in setting EVERYTHING view related in a `ViewModel` and NOT in the ViewBag (it's a personal preference, but one that is widely accepted).

If you describe your specific scenario a little further, maybe I can help you come up with a better pattern to follow.

```
public class LayoutViewModel
{
   public bool UseFacebookConnect { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class SomeViewModel : LayoutViewModel
{
   public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var someViewModel = new SomeViewModel 
                {
                    SomeData = "", 
                    UseFacebookConnect = true
                };

                return View(someViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: I have a the FaceBook Connect JavaScript code inside masterpage, but I need to hide it on some of the pages that don't need the social functionality.

Comment: So pass a bool in your ViewBag. `ViewBag["useFacebookConnect"] = false;` from the Controller... not from the view. I'd put the logic in an `ActionFilter` in order to keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).