# How to hide status query string from Url after updating from MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view which shows info according to a specific Id.

My Controller is:

```
 public ActionResult ModifyWorkout(string WorkoutId, bool? Status)
    {
        Guid pkWorkoutId = new Guid(WorkoutId);
        BLLWorkouts _objBLLWorkouts = new BLLWorkouts();
        var WorkoutRow = _objBLLWorkouts.GetOneWorkout(pkWorkoutId);
        WorkoutModel PageModel = new WorkoutModel
        {
            pkWorkoutId = WorkoutRow.pkWorkoutId,
            WorkoutName = WorkoutRow.WorkoutName,
            WorkoutNote = WorkoutRow.WorkoutNote,
            Sessions = WorkoutRow.Sessions,
            CmpFlag = WorkoutRow.CmpFlag,
            tblWorkoutSessions = WorkoutRow.tblWorkoutSessions
        };
        ViewBag.UpdateStatus = Status;
        return View(PageModel);
    }
```

I always pass a Query String as Workout id for getting a single record. But when I update that records it is posting to another action:

```
 public ActionResult UpdateWorkout(WorkoutModel model)
    {
        bool _status = false;
        BLLWorkouts _objBLLWorkouts = new BLLWorkouts();
        tblWorkout _row = new tblWorkout();
        _row.WorkoutName = model.WorkoutName;
        _row.WorkoutNote = model.WorkoutNote;
        _row.Sessions = model.Sessions;
        _row.pkWorkoutId = model.pkWorkoutId;
        _row.CmpFlag = model.CmpFlag;
        _status = _objBLLWorkouts.UpdateWorkout(_row);

        return RedirectToAction("ModifyWorkout", new { WorkoutId = model.pkWorkoutId, Status = _status });

    }
```

Now problem is that after updating my url becomes like this:

```
/ModifyWorkout?WorkoutId=438b6828-1a21-4ad0-9e40-485dda75b1f6&Status=true"
```

And Status message is shown even after refreshing the page due to `&Status=true` in Url.

```
<div >
            @if (ViewBag.UpdateStatus != null)
            {
                if (ViewBag.UpdateStatus)
                {
                <span class="successmsgCommon">Workout updated successfully.</span>
                }
                else
                {
                <span class="errormsgCommon">Workout was not updated. Please try again.</span>
                }
            }

        </div>
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: **[Check this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199709/2015869)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TempData for this:

```
TempData["Status"] = _status;
return RedirectToAction("ModifyWorkout", new { WorkoutId = model.pkWorkoutId });
```

ASP.NET MVC will store this value for the next request so you can read it in the redirected action.

```
if ((bool)TempData["Status"])
{
    <span class="successmsgCommon">Workout updated successfully.</span>
}
else
{
    <span class="errormsgCommon">Workout was not updated. Please try again.</span>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `TempData` to send the value

```
  TempData["Status"] = true;
```

Consume

```
 if (TempData["Status"])
```

About `TempData`

- TempData is used to pass data from current request to subsequent request means incase of redirection.
- TempData is a dictionary object that is derived from TempDataDictionary class and stored in short lives session

Comment: Thanks Amit Agrawal it worked using Temp Data.I had tried using Temp Date But i assigned it from  ModifyWorkout action instead of UpdateWorkout action.Can we assign value to ViewBag from another action and then redirect to action?