# How to create a multi-step MVC 4 form. (ie wizard)

Tags: c#, jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I am looking to create a Wizard or multi-step form that deals with a Parent and Child object relation ship. Step 1 create parent object and then Step 2 creates the 1st child object.

Models:

```
    public class Company
    {
      [Key]
      public int ID{get;set;}
      public string CompanyName{get;set;}
      public virtual List<Employee> Employees{get;set;}
    }
    public class Employee
    {
      [Key]
      public int ID{get;set;}
      public string EmployeeName{get;set;}
      [ForeignKey("CompanyID")]
      public Company EmployeeCompany{get;set;}
      public int CompanyID {get;set;}
    }
```

The goal is to create a two step form that first takes company information and then goes to employee information.  How would I set up my controllers to handle this? Do I setup two Action results for Company and two for Employee.  Where one actionresult returns a blank/empty form while the second actionresult handles the HttpPost actionresult.

```
    ActionResult CreateCompany()
    {
      //Send back a blank view to create the company
      return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    ActionResult CreateCompany(Company comp)
    {
       //Check comp.id to determine if it is add or update then save changes via entity framework
       //Use newly created ID from database for next step
       Return CreateEmployee(comp.id)
    }
    ActionResult CreateEmployee(int companyid)
    {
       //This is where I get stuck
       //Do I create a new employee object and set the companyid
       return View(); //Blank CreateEmployee View
    }
    [HttpPost]
    ActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
       //Add employee to company and save the company via entity framework
       //Send to next page or next step of wizard
    }
```

Would I be better off using partial views for this? Maybe do some jquery/ajax to post create company and show create employee?

Comment: **[Please check here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199709/2015869)**

Comment: @PKKG Using that example I would store the companyid (Parent Primarykey/foreign key) in the TempData.  Then read on the next post back.  I thought tempdata only lived for one post back?