# How to clear TempData on click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of tabs in my page, each of which holds a different form:

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#overview" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="#reports" data-toggle="tab">Reports</a></li>
<li><a href="#photos" data-toggle="tab">Photos</a></li>
</ul>
```

The tabs are Bootstrap V3.

When a user saves a form I show a success confirmation message using TempData:

```
TempData["success"] = "Your insrecord has been successfully created.";
```

And I display it under the correct tab:

```
@if (TempData["success"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @Html.Raw(@TempData["success"])
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that if a user clicks on one of the tabs, and then clicks back, the TempData is still displayed.  Is there a way to manually clear TempData if the user clicks on any of the tabs?

Comment: **[Check this for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199709/2015869)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TempData is destroyed immediately after the request. So you need not worry about clearing it.

I'm guessing the content of the tab you are seeing is merely client side caching by the browser .. if you were to refresh the page, i'm pretty sure you wont see the content.

Comment: You're correct, but when I switch between tabs I'm not actually refreshing the page, so the TempData is still there - I'd like to clear it when someone clicks on the tab links.

Comment: @BartekMarnane You could use an alert dismiss timeout .. since you are using bootstrap or wireup some javascript to clear the div when you click a tab or something.

Comment: Yeah that sounds good but I don't actually know how to do that. :-)  Is there a resource you can point me to?

Comment: @BartekMarnane if i could see more of your markup i'd be able to help. but its basically some jquery. Give the div an id then say $("#divID").html(''); that should clear it.