# Where to initialize TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need a variable that will be used everywhere (controller, view, master page, ...). I was thinking of putting it in the TempData. Where is the best place to put an object there?

I thought of Page_Load but that's done after the controller.
I thought of the controller Initialize but the TempData seems to be cleared after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't use a session because the data could change on every request. I decided to initialize everything in the OnActionExecuting of the controller and it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Session variable rather than TempData.  Variables stored in TempData will be destroyed after one request: [Difference Between ViewData and TempData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Here is a link documenting the various Client and Server side storage options in Asp.net
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article61.aspx