# How can i maintain objects between postbacks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not so experienced using MVC. I'm dealing with this situation. Everything works well until call the HttpPost method where has all its members null. I don't know why is not persisting all the data on it.

And everything works well, because I can see the data in my Html page, only when the user submit the information is when happens this.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DoTest()
    {
        Worksheet w = new Worksheet(..);
        return View(w);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoTest(Worksheet worksheet)
    {
        return PartialView("_Problems", worksheet);
    }
```

[image]

This is class which I'm using.

```
public class Worksheet
{
    public Worksheet() { }

    public Worksheet(string title, List<Problem> problems)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Problems = problems;
    }

    public Worksheet(IEnumerable<Problem> problems, WorksheetMetadata metadata, ProblemRepositoryHistory history)
    {
        this.Metadata = metadata;
        this.Problems = problems.ToList();
        this.History = history;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Problem> Problems { get; set; }  // Problem is an abstract class
    public WorksheetMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
    public ProblemRepositoryHistory History { get; set; }
}
```

And my razor view.... the razor view shows successfully my view. I realized something rare, please note in my 5 and 6 lines that I have HiddenFor method, well if I used that, when calls HTTPPOST persists the data, I don't know why.

```
@model Contoso.ExercisesLibrary.Core.Worksheet

<div id="problemList">
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Metadata.ExerciseName)</h2>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Metadata.ExerciseName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Metadata.ObjectiveFullName)

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Problems.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
    @Html.Partial(Contoso.ExercisesLibrary.ExerciseMap.GetProblemView(Model.Problems[i]), Model.Problems[i])
    </div>
}
</div>
```

UPDATE
I'm using a static class to get the view name, but as I'm testing I'm just using this Partial view

```
@model Contoso.ExercisesLibrary.AbsoluteArithmetic.Problem1
<div>

    <span style="padding:3px; font-size:18px;">@Model.Number1</span>
    <span style="padding:5px; font-size:18px;">+</span>
    <span style="padding:5px; font-size:18px;">@Model.Number2</span>
    <span style="padding:5px; font-size:18px;">=</span>

    <span style="font-size:18px">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Result, new { style = "width:60px; font-size:18px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Result)
    </span>
</div>

@section Scripts {

}
```

And here the user do the post

```
@model Contoso.ExercisesLibrary.Core.Worksheet

<form method="post">
    @Html.Partial("_Problems", Model)

    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ahem..... I thought one of the biggies of ASP.NET MVC is: *no more postbacks* ...

Comment: You should share your partial view

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Also you did not show where does your code (in the view) call your HttpPost action method

Comment: youve got a few problems. your main one though is that MVC cannot bind to an abstract class. So "Problems" will always have a problem (pun intended)

Comment: One way is to hide all fields in View using Html.HiddenFor(); The other is get those infor from database again.

Comment: I see, what you suggest me.. the Problem list is the main object which I need to recover after post

Comment: Depends on your scenario. What are the derived classes - what do they do? Are theyre multiple ones rendered on the page? also don't use @Html.Partial for forms - the model binder won't work because the form values don't match up to the model hierachy.

Comment: Just Problem1 is derived from Problem

Comment: @DarfZon - why have an abstract class with only one implementation? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RPM1984 It's just a demo, Problem really has more than 100 implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Model Binder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) will 'bind' or link `input` fields on your view to the model. It will not bind display fields (like label), that is why you need the `HiddenFor` it will add an `<input type="hidden"` which will then be bound to the Model when you Post.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you.. but I guess I'm missing something.. please note in the post that I have a Partial View where uses a model called Problem1 and used a EditorFor, so this is an input control and don't get the result after post.

Comment: Problem1 is an implementation of Problem (abstract class)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'TempData'. It is used to pass data from current request to subsequent request means incase of redirection.

This link also helps you.

[TempData](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/9KHW190712-ViewData-vs-ViewBag-vs-TempData-objects-in-mvc3-razor.html)

[SO Tempdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form tag looks like the following, for instance the controller name, action method, the form method and an id for the form. I am referring to the @using statement. In my case the controller name is RunLogEntry, the action method is Create and the id is form.

**Normal Post from View to Controller**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div id="main">
            @Html.Partial("_RunLogEntryPartialView", Model)
        </div>
    }
```

**If you want to post via Jquery, could do the following:**

```
$.post("/RunLogEntry/LogFileConfirmation",
              $("#form").serialize(),
               function (data) {
                   //this is the success event
                   //do anything here you like
                                                            }, "html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a form with correct attribute in your view to perform post action

```
<form action="Test/DoTest" method="post">
...
</form>
```

or

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("DoTest", "Test", FormMethod.Post)) {
...
}
```

The second is recommended.

Comment: true. But i'd suggest @Html.BeginForm instead

Answer (score 0):

Put your entire HTML code under:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
```

tag.