# TempData is empty after RedirectToAction in catch block. What could be the reason?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I've been using TempData for a long time and faced strange issue for me. I have basic scenario:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductCreateModel newProduct)
{
    // create and save product to db

    // try upload product to external site
    try { UploadProductToEbay(newProduct); } 
    catch { 
              TempData["error"] = "error";
              return RedirectToAction("Edit", newProduct.Id);
    }
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    var error = TempData["error"]; // at this point temp data collection is empty and have no idea why
    ...
}
```

The issue takes place when upload fails and `return RedirectToAction("Edit", newProduct.Id);` line is executed. What could be not very obvious reasons of losing temp data values?

**UPDATE:** 
When I use

```
TempData["error"] = "error";
RedirectToAction(...);
```

outside the `catch` block everything works fine, temp data value is transfered to `Edit` action.

Comment: possible answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata

Comment: @user1799320, there is no suitable answer for me.

Comment: @Dmytro - did you find the answer, having similar problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in `return RedirectToAction("Edit", newProduct.Id);` statement.
try this statement instead `return RedirectToAction("Edit", new{Id=newProduct.Id});`
Route Parameter is of `object` type and you passing the `int`.

Comment: This is not the issue, redirect works fine, this is not the actual code, I really use new{Id=newProduct.Id} but the problem is temp data related somehow.

Comment: Okay, You are redirecting from a POST action to GET action, May be this will creating the problem. Me not sure about this.:)

Comment: I've written in update to question that issue takes place only when TempData value assignment and redirect are called in catch block. Otherwise everything works like expected.