# Send Parent ViewData to Partial that is rendered in javascript

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using asp .net core 3, I add some multiple partial via javascript

```
function AddBill(type)
        { tag = "....."; // some div and a tags
                $.get('/Glasses/DisplayFarBill?index=' + farIndex,
                            function (partial) {
                                $('#FarSightedBillsSection').append(tag);
                                $('#farSighted' + farIndex).append(partial);
                                $('#farSighted' + farIndex).collapse('show');
                                farIndex++;
                            });
}
```

I have multiple `ViewData` property on parent that has filled in controller via db context, if I add `partialview` with tag, partials recognize parent `ViewData`, but when I add them via javascript, they don't and I should again fill them in action and access to db multi times.

```
public ActionResult DisplayFarBill(int index)
        {
            ViewData["Index"] = index;

            //ViewData["LenseCover"] = new SelectList(_context.LenseCover, "Id", "Name");
            //ViewData["FrameBrand"] = new SelectList(_context.FrameBrand, "Id", "Name");
            //ViewData["FrameModel"] = new SelectList(_context.FrameModel, "Id", "Name");
            //ViewData["LenseBrand"] = new SelectList(_context.LenseBrand, "Id", "Name");

            BillFarSighted billFarSighted = new BillFarSighted
            {
                PackFactor = 1,
                LenseCoverId = 2
            };
            return PartialView("BillFarSighted", billFarSighted);
        }
```

how can I send Parent ViewData to partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have multiple ViewData property on parent that has filled in
> controller via db context, if I add partialview with tag, partials
> recognize parent ViewData, but when I add them via javascript, they
> don't and I should again fill them in action and access to db multi
> times.

The reason why you can use the partialview tag to get ViewData at once is because the partialview tag is carried out at the same time when the view is loaded, and it is only loaded once.

But when you use `ajax` to get the partialview, the program will enter another action here is `DisplayFarBill`, ***which will make the previously stored ViewData value disappear.***

If you don't want to get the data again in the `DisplayFarBill` action, you can use **TempData** to store it.

It should be noted that the **TempData** storage model needs to be serialized into a json string for transmission, and remember to add `TempData.Keep()` in partial view to keep data for next using.

For the specific difference between TempData and ViewData, please refer to: **[TempData  vs ViewData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/173650/12884742)**

The following is the example where I use TempData:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data=  new SelectList(_context.LenseCover, "Id", "Name");
        TempData["LenseCover"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data); 
        return View(); 
    }
    public ActionResult DisplayFarBill(int index)
    {
        ViewData["Index"] = index; 
        BillFarSighted billFarSighted = new BillFarSighted
        {
            PackFactor = 1,
            LenseCoverId = 2
        };
        return PartialView("BillFarSighted", billFarSighted);
    }
```

BillFarSighted partial view:

```
  @using Newtonsoft.Json;
    @model BillFarSighted
    
    @Html.DropDownList("LenseCover", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SelectListItem>>(TempData["LenseCover"].ToString()).ToList())
    @{TempData.Keep();}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]